# Не проходят данные размером более 2кБ, переданные по MQTT через Ethernet

Tags: ethernet, mqtt, esp32, arduino-ide

Использую связку ESP32, модуль Ethernet W5500, Arduino IDE, библиотека Ethernet, MQTT, библиотека PubSubClient.

Имеется устройство на ESP32, которое отправляет данные в сеть, используя MQTT протокол. На стороне компьютера имеется приложение, подписанное на это устройство, и оно фиксирует все данные, пришедшие от ESP32 по MQTT.

Если ESP32 использует для выхода в сеть WiFi, то проблем не возникает - отправляются и доставляются малые и большие пакеты данных. Но если для выхода в сеть используется Ethernet (DHCP), то возникает проблема при передаче блока данных размером выше 2 кБ - пакет данных теряется. Может пройти пакет размером ровно или менее 2 кБ, свыше 2 кБ - нет. Ковыряние библиотеки Ethernet не привело к успеху.

Кто знает, как убрать ограничение на размер передаваемого блока данных по Ethernet?

Comment: Если ничего не изменилось с тех пор, когда последний раз работал с сетями, то размер пакета ethernet не более ~1500 байт. А раз удаётся передать 2кб, то дело скорей всего не в нём, не в ethernete.

Comment: Хотя пишут придумали таки пакеты увеличенной длины jumbo. Может одно устройство работает с большими пакетами, а другое нет?